# При вводе произвольного числа n в формате (ХХХ) програма выводит его с помощью звёздочек. Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Написать программу, которая просит ввести произвольное целое число (в формате XXX) и выводит его на экран с помощью больших цифр, состоящих из звездочек. Обратите внимание, что один символ может занимать несколько текстовых строк.

К примеру, пользователем было введено число 123. Результатом работы программы может быть:
[image: bruh]
совершенно не имею понятия как изобразить сами числа

Comment: Добро пожаловать! Хорошо бы приложить хотя бы те мысли, которые у вас есть. Решать за кого то тут не особо принято. Может я наведу на мысль, цифры состоят из строк, которые содержат пробельный символ, перевод строки и звездочку. А теперь используя эти знания напишите еденичку в текстовом редакторе.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! **Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос.** Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи**. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Answer (score 3):

Хоть и не принято решать за других, но вот можно, как то так

```
from art import tprint
number = input().strip()
tprint(number, '#')
```

Comment: Классная библиотека в коллекцию, спасибо)

Answer (score 2):

```
dct = {'1': ['*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
       '2': ['***', '  *', '***', '*  ', '***'],
       '3': ['***', '  *', '***', '  *', '***']}
w = '321'
s = '#'

print(*(' '.join(z).replace('*', s) for z in zip(*(dct[x] for x in w))), sep='\n')

### ### #
  #   # #
### ### #
  # #   #
### ### #
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dct = {
    '1': ['#', '#', '#', '#', '#'],
    '2': ['###', '  #', '###', '#  ', '###'],
    '3': ['###', '  #', '###', '  #', '###'],
}

def xxx(n):
    for x in zip(*map(dct.__getitem__, n)):
        print(*x)

xxx('32321')
### ### ### ### #
  #   #   #   # #
### ### ### ### #
  # #     # #   #
### ### ### ### #
```